# Spring Integreation Last Successful Poll Timestamp

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to find out when the last time spring integration successfully checked for messages? Specifically, the last time it ran, without error, regardless of whether it found content that it could turn into a message?

I have a mail inbound channel adapter (with a poller) connected to a router that spits the messages out to various channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual polling logic is encapsulated with the internal `Callable<Boolean> pollingTask` implementation in the `AbstractPollingEndpoint`:

```
Callable<Boolean> pollingTask = new Callable<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return doPoll();
    }
};
```

where the `boolean` return means that we have extracted and sent a message or not.

This `pollingTask` can be wrapped with the AOP `adviceChain` meaning that we can **intercept** that `doPoll()` method. Therefore it is a place where your can track `last time spring integration successfully checked for messages`.

Consider implement the `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor`.